# How to use two different .format() with using one for-loop

Tags: python, for-loop, format

So I have been trying to figure out how I can print out two different formats using one for loop. I would like to provide the code before explaining my issue

```
fullList = [
  {
    'url': 'www.randomsite.com/251293',
    'numbers': '7.5'
  },
  {
    'url': 'www.randomsite.com/251294',
    'numbers': '8'
  },
  {
    'url': 'www.randomsite.com/251295',
    'numbers': '8.5'
  },
  {
    'url': 'www.randomsite.com/251296',
    'numbers': '9'
  },
  {
    'url': 'www.randomsite.com/251297',
    'numbers': '9.5'
  }
]

#fullList = [
#  {
#    'numbers': '7.5'
#  },
#  {
#    'numbers': '8'
#  },
#  {
#    'numbers': '8.5'
#  },
#  {
#    'numbers': '9'
#  },
#  {
#    'numbers': '9.5'
#  }
#]

try:
    numbersList = []
    for numbers in fullList:
        numbersList.append('{}{}'.format('{}'.format(numbers.get('url') if numbers.get('url') else ''), numbers.get('numbers')))

    print(numbersList)
except Exception:
    pass
```

and what I am looking for outcome is:

If url is in the list: `print('<url|numbers>')` meaning the format would be `<url|numbers>`

If no url is in the list: `print(numbers)` and the print here should only give the numbers - *I sometimes just want the numbers, meaning that in the list I removed all URL's so it will only remain numbers.*

My problem is that I dont know how I can combine these two into one format. So far I am able to print out only numbers with the code I have provided.

Comment: why don't you use normal `if/else` to do this - it will be more readable.

Comment: @furas Hmm nothing I would thought about, Could you provide a example of how it would look etc? Would appreciate it alot!

Comment: instead of `'{}'.format(something)` you can use directly `something`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use normal `if/else`. It will be more readable. And you have only one format.

```
for numbers in fullList:
    if numbers.get('url'):
        numbersList.append('{}|{}'.format(numbers.get('url'), numbers.get('numbers'))
    else:
        numbersList.append(numbers.get('numbers'))
```

Comment: This was actually pretty more clear I would say and easier to configure if any changes for future :)

Answer (score 1):

Using list comprehension

**Ex.**

```
fullList = [
  {'url': 'www.randomsite.com/251293','numbers': '7.5'},
  {'url': 'www.randomsite.com/251294','numbers': '8'},
  {'url': 'www.randomsite.com/251295','numbers': '8.5'},
  {'url': 'www.randomsite.com/251296','numbers': '9'},
  {'url': 'www.randomsite.com/251297','numbers': '9.5'}
]

list1 = [ "{0}|{1}".format(x['url'],x['numbers']) for x in fullList ]
print(list1)
```

**O/P:**

```
['www.randomsite.com/251293|7.5', 'www.randomsite.com/251294|8', 'www.randomsite.com/251295|8.5', 'www.randomsite.com/251296|9', 'www.randomsite.com/251297|9.5']
```

**OR**

for the updated question, if the dictionary does not contain `url`

```
fullList = [
  {'url': 'www.randomsite.com/251296','numbers': '9'},
  {'numbers': '9.5'}
]
list1 = [ "{0}{1}".format((x.get('url')+'|' if 'url' in x else ''),x.get('numbers','')) for x in fullList ]
print(list1)
```

**O/P:**

```
['www.randomsite.com/251296|9', '9.5']
```

Comment: Hmm however the problem here is that if I now etc remove the URL's through the list, this would not give me a correct outprint, correct?

Comment: @Thrillofit86 If you know dictionary has to contain key then no need to use if else condition, you try with a simple list  comprehension.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to select all `values` in each subdict and `join` them with a custom delimiter. In this way, you don't care if the key/value exist or not.

```
# Let's consider partial data
fullList = [
    {
        'url': 'www.randomsite.com/251293',
        'numbers': '7.5'
    },
    {
        'url': 'www.randomsite.com/251294',
        'numbers': '8'
    },
    {
        'url': 'www.randomsite.com/251295',
        'numbers': '8.5'
    },
    {
        'url': 'www.randomsite.com/251296',
    },
    {
        'numbers': '9.5'
    }
]


numbersList = []
for element in fullList:
    numbersList.append("|".join([element[v] for v in element.keys()]))

print(numbersList)
# ['www.randomsite.com/251293|7.5', 'www.randomsite.com/251294|8',
#     'www.randomsite.com/251295|8.5', 'www.randomsite.com/251296', '9.5']
```

You can do it in one line with list comprehension:

```
output = ["|".join([element[v] for v in element.keys()]) for element in fullList]
print(output)
# ['www.randomsite.com/251293|7.5', 'www.randomsite.com/251294|8', 
# 'www.randomsite.com/251295|8.5', 'www.randomsite.com/251296', '9.5']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this problem and it will look more **pythonic** this way:

```
fullList = [
  {'url': 'www.randomsite.com/251293', 'numbers': '7.5'}, 
  {'url': 'www.randomsite.com/251294', 'numbers': '8'}, 
  {'url': 'www.randomsite.com/251295', 'numbers': '8.5'}, 
  {'url': 'www.randomsite.com/251296', 'numbers': '9'}, 
  {'url': 'www.randomsite.com/251297', 'numbers': '9.5'}, 
  {'numbers': '100'}
]


[(x['url'] + '|' + x['numbers']) if x.get('url') else x['numbers'] for x in fullList ]
```

You are using list comprehensions, minimizing nesting etc.

Comment: Right! This is wokring aswell as @furas example, Does the same thing just that Furas is using if else statements to be able to see the code more clear. However this works pretty well too :)